# Indexing issue shopware 6

Tags: shopware

Question,

the website create with shopware keeps indexing all pages but with over 30/35k items it slows down the page and admin, is it possible to only do this in the weekend?

[image]

this is currently done automaticly but i need this to be done on a set time/date

Please help me on this.

regards,

Answer (score 2):

It is highly **recommended** to **disable** the [Admin Worker](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/tutorials-and-faq/message-queue-and-scheduled-tasks#admin-worker) in production environments. The Admin Worker is enabled by default and runs automatically when a user is logged in to the Administration.

Especially with lots and lots of entities, like products, categories etc., the Admin Worker is hitting its limits and a dedicated service (e.g. RabbitMQ) should be used instead.

Please refer to the documentation:

- https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/tutorials-and-faq/message-queue-and-scheduled-tasks#disable-admin-worker-set-up-cli-worker
- https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/hosting/infrastructure/message-queue#message-queue-on-production-systems